# can any one put command to install kazam screen recorder with webcam

Tags: kazam

can any one have command to install Kazam screen recorder with web cam?
i have command to install Kazam but it only facilitate screen recorder not give web cam facility at a same time.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "install Kazam screen recorder with web cam"?  Do you mean you want to record what's on the webcam screen, what's on your screen at the same time as recording from the webcam, or that you want to use kazam to capture from your webcam?

Comment: means kazam give facility of screen recorder with web-cam at same time so we can record screen as well as use web-cam too. but in old version only screen recorder is available so i need latest which provide screen-recorder as well as web-cam recording at same time @anonymous2

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: how can i know about that ? @anonymous

Comment: Go to the terminal and type `lsb_release -a`.  You should see a line that says, `Description:    Ubuntu xx.xx [LTS]`.  Paste in that line.

Comment: Or actually, you could paste in the line that says `Release:   xx.xx`

Comment: Description: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS @anonymous2

Answer (score 0):

**Kazam Screencaster** will already detect your Webcam, make sure your Webcam drivers are installed correctly and they're allowed by the **3rd party applications**.

If you already have done that and your webcam isn't yet supported by K**azam Screencaster**.

Try the following for **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** (your operating system as I understood from the comments):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kazam-team/unstable-series
```

NOTICE: If you get "`sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found`" - you can easily install it using "apt-get" by typing:

```
apt-get -y install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

Now update your sources.list by typing:

```
apt-get -y update
```

Now install Kazam and it's required packages:

```
apt-get -y install kazam python3-cairo python3-xlib
```